# Collection <__NSCFString:> was mutated while being enumerated crash

Tags: ios, contacts, addressbook, mutated

For some reason, I am getting a crash (noted below) saying "Collection <__NSCFString: 0x155cefd0> was mutated while being enumerated", but only on an actual device. It works on the Xcode test device. I'm not entirely sure what that means, so how do I approach this lldb crash?

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil);
        ABRecordRef pet = ABPersonCreate();
        ABRecordSetValue(pet, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef)petFirstName, nil);
        ABRecordSetValue(pet, kABPersonLastNameProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef)petLastName, nil);

        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef)petPhoneNumber, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(pet, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil);

        ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBookRef, pet, nil);

        NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
        for (id record in allContacts){
            ABRecordRef thisContact = (__bridge ABRecordRef)record; //*******The line below is where the crash is occurring*********   
            if (CFStringCompare(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(thisContact),
                                ABRecordCopyCompositeName(pet), 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo){
                //The contact already exists!
                //detects if duplicate

                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is that the exact code or do you attempt to delete the dupe or some such?

Comment: And are you sure `allContacts` is an NSArray?  The message kind of suggests that it's a NSString.

Comment: This is the exact code from my Xcode project unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm...so I'm not allocating allContacts or something?

Comment: It fails only on an actual device. It works on the test device. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: No idea -- never played with the address book stuff.

Comment: This code looks like it is leaking memory. `ABRecordCopyCompositeName` will return a `CFStringRef` that you need to release, you'll need to save these in separate variables so that you can release them after the compare.

Comment: Interesting, so how would I fix something like that.           [ABRecordCopyCompositeName release];?

Comment: It's because I disabled arc. Unfortunately, I have to disable arc to use nsxml. So how do I go about doing this without arc?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing a collection at some other point of your application. According to Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html)
**"It is not safe to remove, replace, or add to a mutable collection’s elements while enumerating through it"** 
Please check the following:

1. Which collections are you working with in your app, that could be
   modify while your above code is running.
2. If you need to modify any
   collection while iterating through it, use suggested techniques in
   linked docs.